# How to prevent automatic newlines, when the output is wider than the console?

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application, game-engine

I'm implementing the game of life, using console output. So far it's looking good:

[image: Before]

However, when I make the width of the output larger than the with of the console, this happens:

[image: After]

Instead of letting the lines run offscreen, it inserts a newline. Is there a way to turn this off?

I'm on a small laptop, so changing the [console width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.windowwidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't really help.

Comment: Maybe you can check this property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.windowwidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Not exactly what are you looking for but maybe can help to solve sour issue :)

Comment: What do you expect it to do in the second case? Consoles by nature don't generally have horizontal scroll bars

Comment: @krekkon Unfortunately it doesn't, I'm on a fairly small screen, and I'd like the output to be bigger. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Please check my answer, and try out the links.

Comment: You'll need to cull your "viewport". Like any game.. you only draw whats visible on the screen. You would have to simulate a camera to move left and right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to get and set the maximum length of the screen.

So you get the [length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.windowwidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you need more space you can [set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setwindowsize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the windows size :)
Dont forget to set the [BufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setbuffersize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) too

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer my question. I'm on a small laptop, so my windowSize caps at [169,57]. I was hoping it was possible to create longer lines than that.

Comment: You can modify it, lets try with hand: Click left upper corner logo in the command window => properites  => Layout => windows size Widt and buffer size width set you desired value

Comment: And as the links says you can do that from code too. :)

Comment: If you want a horizontal scrollbar, you modify just the buffer value

Comment: So it was the answer to your question? :)